# Use values from one table in the bin operator of another table

Tags: azure-data-explorer

Consider the following query:

This will generate a 1 cell result for a fixed value of bin_duration:

```
events
| summarize count() by id, bin(time , bin_duration) | count
```

I wish to generate a table with variable values of bin_duration.

bin_duration will take values from the following table:

```
range bin_duration from 0 to 600 step 10;
```

So that the final table looks something like this:

[image: bin_duration]

How do I go about achieving this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please clarify the output? Consider you have the next input: 
let _data = range x from 0 to 1000 step 1 
| extend ['time'] = datetime(2019-04-12) + x*1min;
_data 
.. what is the output that you expect?

Answer (score 0):

The [`bin(value,roundTo)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/binfunction) aka `floor(value,roundTo)`, will round `value` down to the nearest multiple of `roundTo`, so you don't need an external table.

```
events 
| summarize n = count() by bin(duration,10) 
| where duration between(0 .. 600) 
| order by duration asc
```

You can try this out on the [Stormevents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/tutorial) tutorial:

```
let events = StormEvents | extend duration = (EndTime - StartTime) / 1h;
events 
| summarize n = count() by bin(duration,10) 
| where duration between(0 .. 600) 
| order by duration asc
```

When dealing with timeseries data, `bin()` also understands the handy [timespan literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/timespan), ex.:

```
let events = StormEvents | extend duration = (EndTime - StartTime);
events 
| summarize n = count() by bin(duration,10h) 
| where duration between(0h .. 600h) 
| order by duration asc
```